# Flutter web downloads about 5 MB on each run (demo app)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Here is a fresh default code run. Flutter web is downloading too many files. they size about 5 MB, is there any 'production mode' like Angular ? I couldn't find such option yet or I don't know how to mention such issue. thank you for help.

[image: Here is a fresh default code run.]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are running your Flutter web app in **debug mode**, i.e. you are seeing a *debug version* of your app.
This debug version is built using DDC ([Dart dev compiler](https://dart.dev/tools/dartdevc)), which "supports incremental compilation and emits modular JavaScript".

This results in large file sizes. If you want to see the *release version* of your app, you need to run `flutter build web`, which will build your app in release mode and consequently emit tiny JS files in comparison.

[Learn more about web release builds](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/web).